# FQL - "An access token is required to use this resource."

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get all of my status updates and display them in my app. I have the OAuth token stored in a database.

This code retrieves the access_token from the database, and constructs a url to query

```
include ('fbconfig.php');
include ('inc/facebook.php');

// make new facebook object
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => APP_ID,
        'secret' => APP_SECRET,
        'cookie' => true
));

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

// get the access token from database 
$sql = "SELECT fb_token FROM users";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$access_token = $row[0];

// fql query to get fb status updates
$fql = "SELECT uid,time,message FROM status WHERE uid = me()";

// construct query url
$fql_query_url = "https://graph.facebook.com"
. "/fql?q=" . urlencode($fql)
. '&' . $access_token;

echo $fql_query_url;
```

After the above code is run, it outputs this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+uid%2Ctime%2Cmessage+FROM+status+WHERE+uid+%3D+me%28%29&293721510781740|
```

This error is thrown when I click the link (even though it says I have an access_token in the url):

```
{"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104}}
```

I have been at this for hours doing different variations of this, and I don't understand why it's not retrieving my statuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the url contain

&access_token=<access token here>

?

Try by replacing:

```
$fql_query_url = "https://graph.facebook.com"
. "/fql?q=" . urlencode($fql)
. '&' . $access_token;
```

by:

```
$fql_query_url = "https://graph.facebook.com"
. "/fql?q=" . urlencode($fql)
. '&access_token=' . $access_token;
```